# Views and arguments in url

Tags: php, drupal

I have made 2 views: 'list' and 'maps'

The 'list' view has an exposed filter input field (called title)

I try made a link in the head-section of the list-view (text-format: PHP-code) to the maps-view.

My question is, how can I do this with the `GET` method?

This code don't work:

```
<a href="maps?title=<?php $_GET['title'] ?>">maps</a>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's easy :) you missed the `echo`:

```
<a href="maps?title=<?php echo $_GET['title'] ?>">maps</a>
#                         ^^^^
```

---

edit: there is also a `<?=` opening tag (instead of `<?` and `<?php`) which automatically calls echo (e.g. `<?= $_GET['title'] ?>`) but [some people find them bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php). Especially that modern frameworks such as Symfony2 recommend to disable short_open_tags.